# Running synchronous tests with robotium on multiple devices

Tags: android, robotium, synchronous

I have two apps i need to test, the two apps respond to each other
1. App A is the user App in which he is doing his activity, more specifically submit orders
2. App B is the supplier App in which he recipes the client orders

both Apps need to run on separate devices by definition

my test flow is as follow
1. Client And Supplier have their app open
2. Client Issue an order
3. Supplier receive order
4. Supplier accept order
5. Supplier fulfill order
6. Client get notification the order was fulfilled

I can program the tests separately in robotium, problem is i need them to be synchronous - since the entire process is a real-time one in Real life

any one know how i can do that? (without creating million small robotium tests and run them one after the other)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make them wait for a certain element to appear. You can do that with the following snippets:

**Activity**

```
solo.waitForActivity(solo.getCurrentActivity().toString());
```

**Toast** and more specifically the text in the toast

```
solo.waitForText("Some text inside toast");
```

**Waiting for view to disappear**

```
TextView textField = solo.getText("My Text Value", true);
  solo.waitForCondition(new Condition() {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied() {
    return textField.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE;
  }
}, 1000);
```

**Fragments**

```
 solo.waitForFragmentByTag("MyTag");
```

So you have to give some clue that an order has been submitted. You can do that with the elements that we can wait for. After the waiting is over do whatever you intended to test.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay.
I already do that, But how can i tell Both "Tests" to Fail at the same time?
i.e. if the message didn't appear on the Client i need the Supplier test to fail as well

Thanks in advnce

Comment: You can set time for Timing out on the wait for on the receiver that means that they might not fail at the same time but for the same test case.